# Converting inner array into Hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following array

```
a=[["name","age"],
      ["Raja","29"],
      ["Gop","30"]
      ["pal","21"]
      ]
```

And I need the following Hash

```
a=[{"name"=>"Raja","age"=>"29"},{"name"=>"Gop","age"=>"30"},{"name"=>"Gop","age"=>"30"},{"name"=>"pal","age"=>"21"}]
```

What it does is, It takes the first row for key and it uses the rest of the array as values as I have shown above.

I have written the following code and it works fine.

```
 myArray = myArray.transpose unless columnHeaders
    arrayHash = []
    (1..myArray.length - 1).each do |i|
      rowHash = OrderedHash.new
      (0..myArray[i].length - 1).each do |j|
        rowHash[myArray[0][j]] = myArray[i][j]
      end
      arrayHash << rowHash
    end
    return arrayHash
```

But I feel like the above codes doesn't fall under Ruby style of coding, Is there any way I code better in Ruby style? Can You help me to write ruby idiomatic code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
a = [['name', 'age'], ['Raja', '29'], ['Gop', '30'], ['pal', '21']]
a[1..-1].map { |element| a[0].zip(element).to_h }
#=> [
#     { "name" => "Raja", "age" => "29" },
#     { "name" => "Gop", "age" => "30" },
#     { "name" => "pal","age" => "21" }
#   ]
```

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product) and [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
a = [['name','age'], ['Raja','29'], ['Gop','30'], ['pal','21']]
[a[0]].product(a[1..-1]).map(&:transpose).map(&:to_h)
#⇒ [{"name"=>"Raja", "age"=>"29"},
#   {"name"=>"Gop", "age"=>"30"},
#   {"name"=>"pal", "age"=>"21"}]
```

Comment: I doubt it’s simpler and easier. I think the greeny should go to @spickermann since his solution does one iteration through the array. I just showed another approach, but I am not sure at all it’s better.

Comment: Actually I thought it uses the existing methods so efficiently!

Comment: especially I like the use product method!